# Constant scans and compute scalars in execution plan when joining table and temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I'm checking if this statement could take less time to execute. The execution plan is absolutely confusing. The query and plan are below.

There is a join between temp table and normal table with clustered index on Date column. Table contains ~1000 rows and temp table has a bit over 1 million.

In execution plan this join is reflected in two nested loops with lots of strange things like Constant Scans and Compute Scalars taking part in the process.

Clustered Index Seek here takes 74% and estimated number of rows is 1 there. Actual number of rows is huge.

```sql
    select t.StartDateTime
        , t.EndDateTime
        , t.StartDateTime_BusinessHours
        , t.EndDateTime_BusinessHours
        , count (c.Date) as DaysOffCount
    --into #DaysOff
    from #CorrectedStartEndDateTime as t
    left join util.Calendar as c on c. Date >= t.StartDateTime_BusinessHours and c. Date <= t.EndDateTime_BusinessHours and c.IsDayOff = 1
    group by t.StartDateTime
        , t.EndDateTime
        , t.StartDateTime_BusinessHours
        , t.EndDateTime_BusinessHours
```

Here is a link to the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1crVr6rB

Temporary table is a 'select into' dump from another query without any indexing. And table looks this way:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [util].[Calendar](
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [IsDayOff] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DaysTillNextBusinessDay] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Date] ASC)
)
```

I would expect this to be a simple nested loop between temp table scan and clustered index seek or anything similar, could you please help me understand what's happenning and why?

Comment: If you're going to provide an execution plan, use [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/); images won't help us as we can't interact with an image. Can include the DDL of your objects and the relevant indexes too please? I note you're using a temporary table too; are you indexing that if it contains a large number of rows?

Comment: @Larnu, thank you so much for advice! I have added the link to execution plan and create table statement to the question text. Temporary table is created with select into and has no indexing.

Comment: So does your table `Calendar` have no indexes apart from the one on `[Date]`?

Comment: @Larnu, that's correct

Comment: What data type are t.StartDateTime_BusinessHours and t.EndDateTime_BusinessHours?  Do they match the data type of c.Date?

Comment: both are datetime and c.Date is date

Comment: Can you dump Calendar into a temp table with data type of datetime for [Date], and see if your execution plan looks better?  You could also modify the index on this temp Calendar table to be on Date but INCLUDE [IsDayOff].

Comment: @ChrisHackett, it is clustered index. It includes all columns already by definition. Making types match is a valid point.

Comment: Vladimir I overlooked that, I read Larnu's comment about index on Date, assumed nonclustered - woops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all the details of these additional operators in the plan, but they are very cheap. Most likely they are added to the plan because there is a mismatch in types of `Calendar.date` and  `StartDateTime_BusinessHours`, `EndDateTime_BusinessHours`.

You can see a call to internal function

```
GetRangeWithMismatchedTypes([tempdb].[dbo].[#CorrectedStartEndDateTime].[StartDateTime_BusinessHours] as [t].[StartDateTime_BusinessHours],NULL,(22))
```

in the plan. Engine has to compare somehow `date` with `datetime` and these strange looking operators are introduced to avoid conversion of `date` into `datetime`, so that index still could be used.

The plan itself looks fine. I doubt you can make it run significantly faster.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128526/having-hard-time-understanding-expressions-in-below-query-plan for more details about `GetRangeWithMismatchedTypes`.

---

I don't think that it is a problem in this specific query that there is a big difference in the number of estimated and actual rows in the index seek of the `Calendar` table. I think that this mis-estimation doesn't make the query run slower.

---

You can try to rewrite the query using `OUTER APPLY` to avoid `GROUP BY`. It may be a bit faster.

```
select 
    t.StartDateTime
    , t.EndDateTime
    , t.StartDateTime_BusinessHours
    , t.EndDateTime_BusinessHours
    , A.DaysOffCount
--into #DaysOff
from 
    #CorrectedStartEndDateTime as t
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS DaysOffCount
        FROM
            util.Calendar as c
        WHERE
            c.Date >= t.StartDateTime_BusinessHours 
            and c.Date <= t.EndDateTime_BusinessHours 
            and c.IsDayOff = 1
    ) AS A
;
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, I have changed the Calendar table to have datetime and it removed the 'strange' operators. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJXAJUprr
However I'm still wondering why there is such mismatch between estimated and actual numbers of rows in the index seek

Comment: "why there is such mismatch between estimated and actual numbers of rows in the index seek". It is a pretty low-level stuff. I think there are more chances of getting a good answer to this question if you ask it on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ivanochkah, I also added another version of the query, which may be a bit faster. You'll need to check.

Comment: Thank you! Will try that out.